# Laravel SocialiteProviders/saml2 error during callback

Tags: laravel, saml-2.0, laravel-socialite

I'm using [socialiteprovider/saml2](https://socialiteproviders.com/Saml2/?#installation-basic-usage) for my web to intergrate with saml idp,let say right now im using [mocksaml](https://mocksaml.com/) to test in my localhost, however during callback process I keep on getting error.

config/services.php

```
'saml2' => [
    'acs' => 'https://mocksaml.com/api/saml/sso',
    'metadata' => file_get_contents(storage_path('saml/mock-saml-metadata.xml')),
    'entityid' => 'https://saml.example.com/entityid',
    'certificate' => file_get_contents(storage_path('saml/mock-saml-cert.pem')),
],
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/auth/redirect', function () {
    return Socialite::driver('saml2')->redirect();
});

Route::post('/auth/callback', function () {
    $user = Socialite::driver('saml2')->user();
    // $user = Socialite::driver('saml2')->stateless()->user();
});
```

I already follow exactly the same as the documentation. But the error still persists, most the issue i found is adding stateless() but still not working.

the error I got

without stateless:

[image]

with stateless

[image]

I got no idea how to fix this but there must be something wrong somewhere. :(

i tried using stateless, add session domain

Comment: Did you end up ever figuring this out? I'm having this exact issue right now.